# Random coordinates in Android App

Tags: java, android, random

I have an app with a sprite that moves around.  What I'm trying to do is get the sprites starting position to be random.  I'm okay with the 'x' coordinate, I just want the 'y' coordinate to be random.

In the code below I have set a random object and I have a 'y' coordinate set but I don't know how to marry the two so that it begins in a random place.  Ideally, I would want the sprite to start in a random place every time it goes off screen and comes back on but first I want to get it started in random place:

```
package cct.mad.lab;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import java.util.Random;


public class Sprite {

//x,y position of sprite - initial position (0,50)
private int x = 0; 
private int y = 50;
private int xSpeed = 80;//Horizontal increment of position (speed)
private int ySpeed = 5;// Vertical increment of position (speed)
private GameView gameView;
private Bitmap spritebmp;
//Width and Height of the Sprite image
private int bmp_width;
private int bmp_height;
// Needed for new random coordinates.
private Random random = new Random();



public Sprite(GameView gameView) {
      this.gameView=gameView;
      spritebmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameView.getResources(),
              R.drawable.sprite_robot);
      this.bmp_width = spritebmp.getWidth();
      this.bmp_height= spritebmp.getHeight();
 }
//update the position of the sprite
public void update() {
    x = x + xSpeed;
    y = y + ySpeed;
    wrapAround(); //Adjust motion of sprite.
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    //Draw sprite image
    canvas.drawBitmap(spritebmp, x , y, null);
}

public void wrapAround(){
    //Code to wrap around   
    if (x < 0) x = x + gameView.getWidth(); //increment x whilst not off screen
    if (x >= gameView.getWidth()){ //if gone of the right sides of screen
            x = x - gameView.getWidth(); //Reset x
    }
    if (y < 0) y = y + gameView.getHeight();//increment y whilst not off screen
    if (y >= gameView.getHeight()){//if gone of the bottom of screen
        y -= gameView.getHeight();//Reset y
    }
}

}
```

As always, any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly is your problem. There is a [`Random.nextInt(int max)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) method so you could do something like

```
public Sprite(GameView gameView) {
      this.gameView=gameView;
      spritebmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameView.getResources(),
              R.drawable.sprite_robot);
      this.bmp_width = spritebmp.getWidth();
      this.bmp_height= spritebmp.getHeight();

      this.x = random.nextInt(gameView.getWidth());
      this.y = random.nextInt(gameView.getHeight());
}
```

Is this what you are looking for or do you have troubles in some other place?

Comment: Thanks for that.  Gave me what I needed